# if model invalid then repoulate the files uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

On create action i'm allowing the user to upload a picture file, and based on the following view model if it is invalid during post action the message appear and the model is repopulated again with user's input except the file.
i'm not sure if i can repopulate the file when the model is invalid

ViewModel

```
public class CreateEditChildViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string EducationalLevel { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

Post Action

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateEditChildViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

                var child = new Childs()
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    ParentOfId = model.ParentId,
                    SpecialistOfId = model.SpecialistId,
                    DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth,
                    Gender = model.Gender,
                    ...................
                };
                _db.Childs.Add(child);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (files.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "images");
                    var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
                    using (var filesStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, child.Id + extension), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        files[0].CopyTo(filesStream);
                    }
                    child.Picture = @"\images\" + child.Id + extension;
                }

                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            CreateEditChildViewModel modelVM = new CreateEditChildViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                ....................
                //All model properties
            };
            return View(modelVM);
        }
```

To sum up my question i would like to save the file input in case if the model is invalid i don't make the user to re-upload the file

[image]

Comment: Client side validation can solve this problem for you, unless you require some kind of server side validation.

Comment: Hi @Amani,any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ajax` partial refresh to upload data to the backend, which will keep the state of the client page. The error can be judged by h5 or customlize error.

Here is the example(take the `FirstName` and `LastName` as examples).

ViewModel(Add File attribute):

```
 public class CreateEditChildViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //...
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Your View:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="error"></div>
<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
<label asp-for="@Model.FirstName"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.FirstName" />
<label asp-for="@Model.LastName"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.LastName" />
<input asp-for="@Model.File" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub" />
</form>
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: "/Home/Create",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data == 'Index') {
                        location.href = '/home/index'
                    } else {
                        $('#error').text('please fill in valid data')
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                }
            })
        })
</script>
}
```

Post Action(Change the return data of the background to json):

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateEditChildViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

            var child = new Childs()
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                //...................
            };
            _db.Childs.Add(child);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (files.Count() > 0)
            {
                var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "images");
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
                using (var filesStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, child.Id + extension), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    files[0].CopyTo(filesStream);
                }
                child.Picture = @"\images\" + child.Id + extension;
            }

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json("Index");
        }

        CreateEditChildViewModel modelVM = new CreateEditChildViewModel()
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            //....................
        };
        return Json(modelVM);
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: What if i have a line with `ModelState.AddModelError("Count", "Please write correct count.");` in server side how can i show that error ??

Comment: Add `<span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("Count")</span>`